# Augmented Reality in the Manufacturing World

Tags: augmented-reality

Have been doing a lot of exploration around augmented reality and object recognition of late and primarily around its use in the manufacturing world - using marker identification its not a problem , but have scenarios for maintenance where by would like to use it as real world object recognition. Take this scenario an room contains 5 identical pieces of equipment and want person to be able to walk into room and be pointed to the exact equipment that requires maintenance they will already have been informed automatically that this is needed - the question for me is has anyone any experience with a method or platform that can actually achieve this - all equipment will be absolutely identical to me the only reliable way is via a distinct identification i.e. a marker or serial as such to try an rely on indoor gps or other when all equipment maybe within 10ft of each other just wont work ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find you answers in warehousemanagement.
There are several wmsystems who support orderpicking in detail and can situate exact locations of object in the space.
Next step is to define when your object needs maintenance and create the VR-layer.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Gubberrr - some very interesting concepts there in relation to picking and automation of locations - i guess it comes down to a combination of a location and asset database for physical locations and an identifier to recognize the exact device !